# Can you put ranks into knowledge skills that aren't class skills?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, skills, knowledge-check

Can you put ranks into knowledge skills that aren't class skills?

As a sorcerer, Knowledge Engineering isn't a class skill, can I still put ranks into it so I can do Engineering checks after I level?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Yes.

From the [PRD](http://legacy.aonprd.com/coreRulebook/usingSkills.html):

> Each level, your character gains a number of skill ranks dependent upon your class plus your Intelligence modifier. Investing a rank in a skill represents a measure of training in that skill. You can never have more ranks in a skill than your total number of Hit Dice. **In addition, each class has a number of favored skills, called class skills. It is easier for your character to become more proficient in these skills, as they represent part of his professional training and constant practice. You gain a +3 bonus on all class skills that you put ranks into**. If you have more than one class and both grant you a class skill bonus, these bonuses do not stack.

So, you can put ranks into any skill that you want, class skills will get a +3 bonus on rolls, others will just get the straight rank addition.